# Transform/mirror the variable "remaining day" to "number of days past"

Tags: r

A series of behaviour measurements are collected for each day. In some cases the start of the behaviour is not observed/not measured. However the end of the behaviour are for all groups observed. Therefor the variable "remaining days" simple counts down until the last day (day 1) when the behaviour is observed for the last time. It feels more naturel to count the days when the behaviour starts and I am wondering how can I transform the variable "remaining day" to "number of days past" is possible? Instead of 6 days left 5 days left etc. I would like to get a column which count day 1, day 2 etc. How can I mirror these day for each group that I get the following output.

```
data <- data.frame(Group = as.factor(c("1", "1", "1", "1", 
                                    "1", "1", "2", "2",
                                    "2", "2")),
              remaining.days = as.factor(c("6", "5", "4", "3", 
                                         "2", "1", "4", "3",
                                         "2", "1")),
              behaviour.length = as.numeric(c("21", "42", "12", "33", 
                                                  "12", "32", "15", "65",
                                                  "43", "21")))
```

Expected output

```
> data
   Group remaining.days behaviour.length
1      1              1               21
2      1              2               42
3      1              3               12
4      1              4               33
5      1              5               12
6      1              6               32
7      2              1               15
8      2              2               65
9      2              3               43
10     2              4               21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just reverse the value of for each `Group`

```
transform(data, remaining.days = ave(remaining.days, Group, FUN = rev))

#   Group remaining.days behaviour.length
#1      1              1               21
#2      1              2               42
#3      1              3               12
#4      1              4               33
#5      1              5               12
#6      1              6               32
#7      2              1               15
#8      2              2               65
#9      2              3               43
#10     2              4               21
```

This can be written in `dplyr` and `data.table` as well :

```
#dplyr
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  mutate(remaining.days = rev(remaining.days)) %>%
  ungroup

#data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, remaining.days := rev(remaining.days), Group]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `row_number`

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(Group) %>% 
  mutate(remaining.days = row_number()) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 3
#   Group remaining.days behaviour.length
#   <fct>          <int>            <dbl>
# 1 1                  1               21
# 2 1                  2               42
# 3 1                  3               12
# 4 1                  4               33
# 5 1                  5               12
# 6 1                  6               32
# 7 2                  1               15
# 8 2                  2               65
# 9 2                  3               43
#10 2                  4               21
```